# How to use Npgsql v 6.0.7 in a .net v 4.0 project?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, npgsql

Is there any way to use Npgsql v6.0.7 in a .net v4.0 project? And if there is, can you give instructions?
I need my .net v4.0 to work with PostgreSQL v14.5

Comment: Why are you asking for 4.0 specifically? .NET 4.0 went out of support 6 years ago. No supported Windows version comes with 4.0. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2, which works fine with Npgsql.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.x versions are binary replacements. That means that installing a newer version replaces the older one. You *can't* install an older version over a newer one. Unless you target Windows XP, your machine is running a newer version. It doesn't matter whether your project targets 4.0. It will run on whatever runtime is installed on the machine.

Comment: The last version of Npgsql to work on .NET 4.0 was [2.2.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/2.2.7) released 7 years ago